# How does angular.equals evaluate invalid date objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date

I understand that I shouldn't be using invalid date objects to compare with each other, but for purposes of understanding how and why angular.equal handles something like

```
angular.equals(new Date(''), new Date('')); //returns false, both objects are null
```

on the other hand

```
angular.equals(null, null); //returns true
```

What am I missing here? **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgm106/kjg1a88y/1/)** if you feel the need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using angular <1.2.x you will see that behavior. Because `.equals` implementation only checks for equality of `p1.getTime()` and `p2.getTime()` which in this case is `NaN` and `NaN` is not `NaN`. But 1.2.x onwards that has been changed as there is a recursive check again on the `.equals` and there is a condition:

```
 if (o1 !== o1 && o2 !== o2) return true; // NaN === NaN
```

Which you will see the value returning true in that case.

[>=1.2.x](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f7b999703f4f3bdaea035ce692f1a656b0c1a933/src/Angular.js#L954)

```
  else if (isDate(o1)) {
    if (!isDate(o2)) return false;
    return equals(o1.getTime(), o2.getTime()); //returns false
  }
```

[<1.2.x](https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/blob/master/1.1.0/angular.js#L624)

```
 else if (isDate(o1)) {
    return isDate(o2) && o1.getTime() == o2.getTime(); //returns true
  }
```